# Replacing an integer with space

Tags: java, arrays

I am printing a matrix consisting of numbers and i use a 2d array to store the numbers.I want to replace some of the numbers with space.The following doesn't work since A is an integer.

```
A[randomNum1][randomNum2] = "";
```

Casting is also not possible

```
 A[randomNum1][randomNum2] = (int)"";
```

How can i accomplish this ?

Comment: The question is *why* you want to do that. As you describe it, it's impossible, but if you explained why, perhaps a better solution could be suggested.

Comment: if `A[][]` is an `integer` array, how do you suppose to put `String` values in it?

Comment: Also, `""` is not a space

Comment: In your question you talk about printing, yet the code example are about storing the data. What is it exactly that you have a problem with?

Comment: Can you use an integer value outside of the expected range, like 0 or - 1 to represent your "empty"  value, then use a conditional to present it as a whitespace when you retrieve it? Or (not strong on Java), does Java support a variant data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` is an `int[][]` array, it can't be done. If you use an `Integer[][]` array, you can store `null` instead of an empty `String` in your array (to mark the absence of a value). Then, when you print the array, you can print an empty space when you encounter a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Data types such as int define a set of integers, and nothing else. Reality, however, frequently requires us to distinguish between "one of those values" and "none of them". The term "sparse array" is sometimes used to refer to an array where several (many) elements are absent.

You have several options.

1. Use Integer (as proposed by Eran) and then you have one additional value, i.e., null, to represent "none of them".
2. Set aside one of the int values, e.g., Integer.MIN_VALUE, or, if the values you actually have to store, are non-negative, any negative value to represent "none of them".
3. In addition to an int[] (or int[][]), use some other data structure indicating whether the array value is "none of them". (A BiList might be one possibility.)
4. Use a linked list to store rows, i.e., you don't store the "none of them" at all.

These alternatives each have their drawbacks, and a little OO programming should be used to make their handling easier, i.e., a class SparseArray should be written with get and set methods and a property, isNoneOfThem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you don't want your number to be printed just replace it with a number you won't ever need to store, like NaN or extremely large numbers (0xFFFFFFFF). In your printing code just check the numbers before printing and if the number stored is your space holder number, then just print a space character instead of the number.

The better way would of course include making a new array consisting of booleans and using them to store wether a number should be printed or not.